# DevExtreme - cell with FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, datagrid, asp.net-core-mvc, devextreme

Is there any possibility to create DataGrid cell with FileUpload associated with row.

For example I have database with records and I want to have a possibility to attach files to selected records.

Is someone know how to do that and can share with me ;)

Thanks a lot for your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

A simple demo:

```
<div class="demo-container">
    <div id="gridContainer"></div>
</div>


<script>
    $(function () {
        var customers = [{
            "ID": 1,
            "CompanyName": "Premier Buy",
            "Address": "7601 Penn Avenue South",

        }, {
            "ID": 2,
            "CompanyName": "ElectrixMax",
            "Address": "263 Shuman Blvd",

        }, {
            "ID": 3,
            "CompanyName": "Video Emporium",
            "Address": "1201 Elm Street",

        }]
        $("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
            dataSource: customers,
            showBorders: true,
            columns: ["CompanyName", "Address", {
                dataField: "COLUNIQID",
                alignment: 'center',
                caption: "Actions",
                cellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                    $('<input type="file" />')
                        .on('change', function () {
                            //do the upload here
                            
                        })  
                        .appendTo(container);
                }
            }]
        });

    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @iKremius, Is this solution helpful to you, if yes, you can mark it as answer, thanks :)

Comment: I don't see such an option :/